# Embedding a foursquare map into web site + feature with check-ins

Tags: web, foursquare, checkin

My friends and I start a web/app studio, so we created our own web site.

We have an idea to embed a foursquare map into web site, but it isn't all. A special feature: a map should display our last check-in(my friends and mine) for each user of site. We are four, so - always four check-ins on the map for each guest.

How can we realize this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the 4sq API endpoints? You should use this one https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/recent